# Windows phone create Tap event for each grid row

Tags: c#, grid, windows-phone

I have created a grid dynamically which contents 6 rows. What I want to do is to create a **Tap Event** for each row dynamically. I am not getting how can I create a Tap event for each row.

Is there any examples ? or any solution ?

**My view :**

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="490" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">

    </Grid>
```

This is my grid. I have added column and rows dynamically. so how to create a **Tap Event** for row dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to your problem would be to use a ListBox instead of a grid and use a custom template on the ListBoxItem.

Then when the user taps an item in the listbox you can capture which row they have selected by using the ListBox.SelectedItem / SelectedIndex property

Hope this helps

Grids are more for layout, not for interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a Tap event for a grid row. Put what you can do is putting all the controls of the row in a parent control, and create the event in that control.

For instance (in XAML, but you can do that in C# as well):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
        <!-- Your controls here -->
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
        <!-- Your controls here -->
    </StackPanel>
<Grid>
```

Note that you can use a child grid instead of a stackpanel:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Tap="GridRow_Tap">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Your controls here -->
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Tap="GridRow_Tap">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Your controls here -->
    </Grid>
<Grid>
```

In the C#, to assign an event to a control, use the += operator:

```
 Control.Tap += Control_Tap;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. :)  Please check the question I have edited it.

Comment: @Ajay My answer is still the same. You cannot assign a Tap event to a grid row, so you need to put a parent control in each row you've generated dynamically, and put the Tap event on that control.

Answer (score 0):

i somehow managed to do it
Just had to set the background of the grid row to transparent.
Credit to:
 [Why can't I tap/click blank areas inside of a Border/ContentControl without setting the child's background to transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664251/why-cant-i-tap-click-blank-areas-inside-of-a-border-contentcontrol-without-sett?answertab=votes#tab-top)