# Only the First Item in Horizontal StackPanel is Selectable

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, stackpanel

By my question I mean that I have a horizontal `StackPanel` with a `Tap` event named `stk_Tap1`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tap="stk_Tap1">
    <Rectangle Width="28" Height="28" Fill="{Binding HexColor}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Everything populates ok, the issue arises when an item is tapped. Only when I tap the Rectangle does the Tap event handler fire. When I press the TextBlock nothing happens.

```
private void stk_Tap1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AccentColorListPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var selectedItem = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as ColorItem;

            string itemName = selectedItem.color //the `color` property of the custom ColorItem class I defined is actually the string name of the color

    }
```

I cannot figure out what is driving the issue. Originaly I only had the TextBlock within the StackPanel and it worked fine. I thought though that adding a Rectangle with the Fill of the corresponding TextBlock would be more intuitive for the user, and thus my issue arose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have met with a similar issue. Try setting the stackpanel's background to a solid color or transparent, this solved it for me.

Comment: Perfect. For reference I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx as suggested in the Answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664251/why-cant-i-tap-click-blank-areas-inside-of-a-border-contentcontrol-without-sett .

Answer (score 0):

The Text Block floats over the surface of StackPanel. As tap event is for StackPanel, it only fires when you tap StackPanel. To make that work add tap event to Text Block.